# Combine t.test and var.test into a function in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to combine the f-test and t-test into a function but R kept returning an error.

```
ds <- structure(list(Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Ratings = c(4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L
    )), .Names = c("Gender", "Ratings"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

From basic statistics, if the var.test returns a value > 0.05, the t.test should have the parameter var.equal = TRUE.

Thus

```
> var.test(ds$Ratings~ ds$Gender)

    F test to compare two variances

data:  ds$Ratings by ds$Gender
F = 1.1324, num df = 5, denom df = 5, p-value = 0.8948
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1584512 8.0922265
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
      1.132353
```

And the t.test should be

```
> t.test(ds$Ratings~ ds$Gender, var.equal = TRUE)

    Two Sample t-test

data:  ds$Ratings by ds$Gender
t = 0.1857, df = 10, p-value = 0.8564
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.833149  2.166482
sample estimates:
mean in group F mean in group M 
   3.833333        3.666667
```

I am trying to combine these two into a function such that if the p-value for the var.test < 0.05 then it should set var.equal = FALSE and vice versa. R however, kept returning an error.

```
 super.t <- function(y,x) {
   tmp <- var.test(y~x)
   if tmp$p.value < 0.05 {
     tmp1 <- t.test(y~x, var.equal = FALSE)
   } else {
     tmp1 <- t.test(y~x, var.equal = TRUE) 
   }
   return(tmp1)
 }

 super.t(ds$Ratings~ ds$Gender)
```

Thank you ladies and gentlemen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code didn't work is that you have to put parentheses around your tested `if` condition, like:

```
if (tmp$p.value < 0.05) {
```

You were also calling the function in the wrong way, you needed to just do:

```
super.t(ds$Ratings,ds$Gender)
```

By making use of the formula interface, the `data=` argument, and the fact that `var.equal=` takes a logical value, you could simplify things a fair bit:

```
super.t <- function(form,data,level=0.05) {
  vareq <- var.test(form, data)[["p.value"]] >= level
  t.test(form, data, var.equal = vareq)
}
```

And then call it like:

```
super.t(Ratings ~ Gender, ds)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, sir! Would you also be able to kind of let me know why my original function failed *8 (. Thanks again.

Comment: Gosh, it took me the entire weekends and I was still stuck. Can't believe that the parenthesis for the if condition is the key. Thank you sir, I am forever indebted to you!!!